# How to make part of an image transparent?

Tags: android, delphi, opengl-es, firemonkey

Under delphi (Firmonkey), under android if that matters, I need to make a specific part of a bitmap transparent ie the round corner of the bitmap like in the picture below :

[image: Example of the picture, I want the red part to be transparent]

The bitmap is generated via the `Control.MakeScreenShot`.

I tried to replace all the top left red pixel by transparent pixel like below:

```
    if fScreenShot.Map(TMapAccess.ReadWrite, M) then
    try

      //make the top left corner transparent
      for x := 0 to fScreenShot.Width - 1 do begin
        aContinue := False;
        for y := 0 to fScreenShot.Height - 1 do begin
          if M.GetPixel(X,Y) = _FrameBGColor then begin
            aContinue := True;
            M.SetPixel(X,Y,TalphaColorRec.Null);
          end
          else break;
        end;
        if not aContinue then break;
      end;

    finally
      fScreenShot.Unmap(M);
    end;
```

but the instruction fScreenShot.Map(TMapAccess.ReadWrite, M) is terribly slow (around 200 ms) so I can't do like this :( is there any other way I can go to replace this red color by a transparent color?

**NOTE**: right now (I focus only on android/ios, so on **OpenGL**) the only way I found to clear a region in a canvas is to do

```
Canvas.SaveState;
Canvas.IntersectClipRect(TRectF.create());
Canvas.Clear(TalphaColorRec.Null);
canvas.RestoreState
```

however this work only for rectangular area and can't be applied to my problem :(

**NOTE 2** I'm close to find a workable solution using `blending := False` :

```
Canvas.blending := False;
Canvas.Fill.Color := $00000000;
Canvas.Fill.Kind := TbrushKind.Solid;
canvas.FillRect(TRectF.create(100,100,200,200), //const ARect: TRectF;
                0, 0, //const XRadius, YRadius: Single;
                [], //const ACorners: TCorners;
                1, // const AOpacity: Single;
                TCornerType.round);
Canvas.blending := true;
```

This code actually clear the rectangle. Look good and it's what I want to do with the corner. So I try to replace `FillRect` by `fillpath` and I'm so unlucky it's not work with `fillpath` :( any idea? it's work with `fillEllipse`, `FillRect`, etc, but just with `fillpath` it's not work :(

Comment: I wonder about that 200 ms. I can not measure even one ms. So how do you measure it?

Comment: @TomBrunberg: how it's possible? you did it under windows ? i did it under android and measure it with a TstopWatch

Comment: Ah, ok. Maybe you should add the Android tag then. Yes, I tested in Windows

Comment: ok i added, i didn't even know that it's can matter, but seam as windows is with GDI and android with openGL their is some difference ... This question make me crazy, it's look very trivial but can't found a way

Comment: This might be an incredibly stupid question, but how do those red pixels end up there in the first place? Calling `MakeScreenshot()` seems to produce a valid bitmap with transparencies for me, at least on 10 Seattle with a `TRoundedRectangle`

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful : no because the onpaint of the control is quite complicate (the control is a Tframe with all it's child controls) and the picture i show here in the question is just to make everything more simple to understand

Comment: i edit a little the question regarding maybe a possible opengl solution

Comment: One of the benefits of firemonkey is the possibility to make any control a child of any other control. Given that, is it possible to make the frame a child of a rounded rectangle, and get round it that way?

Comment: @dsm no unfortunately, because under firemonkey clipchildreen not work with the round corner :( so if one childreen is exactly in a corner then the corner will be not drawed because the childreen will paint outside the parent bounds rect :( clipchildreen work only on a rectangular area

Comment: I wasn't thinking of making the frame fill the whole (rounded) rectangle area but rather fall completely within the clipping region. This leaves a margin around the edge that you might not be happy with, admittedly.

Comment: @dsm yes unfortunatly it's not possible :( their is a scrolling box inside the control and no padding :( so i take a screenshot of the full area and then i try to make the (transparent) corner on the screenshot... didn't succeed yet

Comment: Yes, scrolling would look a bit odd. I see your problem.

Comment: yes, thank i m happy you see ... i m close to find a solution, but still not work ... i update the question with the last stuff i found

Comment: ok, i found the solution :) very complicated to do :(

Answer (score 1):

If someone find this and want also the solution, this is how i finally did. at the end i can say that it's seam extremely complicated to do such a trivial think :(

```
{************************************}
{$IF defined(IOS) or defined(android)}
type
  _TcustomCanvasGPUProtectedAccess = class(TcustomCanvasGPU);
{$ENDIF}

{************************************}
{$IF defined(IOS) or defined(android)}
procedure ClearRoundCorner(const aCanvas: Tcanvas; const ARect: TRectF; const ACorner: TCorner);

const
  MinFlatDistance = 4;

var
  Vertices: TCanvasHelper.TVertexArray;
  Colors: TCanvasHelper.TAlphaColorArray;
  Indices: TCanvasHelper.TIndexArray;
  Index, SubdivCount, VertexCount: Integer;
  Offset: integer;
  Angle: Single;
  Radius: TPointF;
  Center, CurPt, OriPt: TPointF;

begin
  Radius.X := ARect.Width;
  Radius.Y := ARect.Height;

  SubdivCount := (Max(Ceil(2 * Pi * Max(Radius.X, Radius.Y) / MinFlatDistance), 40) div 4) * 4; // https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15206
  VertexCount := (SubdivCount div 4) + 1;

  case ACorner of
    TCorner.BottomRight: begin
                           Offset := 0;
                           Center.X := ARect.left;
                           Center.Y := ARect.top;
                           OriPt.X := ARect.left + aRect.width;
                           OriPt.Y := ARect.bottom + aRect.height;
                         end;
    TCorner.BottomLeft: begin
                          Offset := (SubdivCount div 4);
                          Center.X := ARect.Right;
                          Center.Y := ARect.top;
                          OriPt.X := ARect.left - aRect.width;
                          OriPt.Y := ARect.bottom + aRect.height;
                        end;
    TCorner.TopLeft: begin
                       Offset := (SubdivCount div 4) * 2;
                       Center.X := ARect.right;
                       Center.Y := ARect.bottom;
                       OriPt.X := ARect.left - ARect.width;
                       OriPt.Y := ARect.top - aRect.height;
                     end;
    TCorner.TopRight: begin
                        Offset := (SubdivCount div 4) * 3;
                        Center.X := ARect.left;
                        Center.Y := ARect.Bottom;
                        OriPt.X := ARect.right + aRect.width;
                        OriPt.Y := ARect.top - aRect.height;
                      end;
  end;

  SetLength(Vertices, 1 + VertexCount);
  SetLength(Colors, 1 + VertexCount);
  SetLength(Indices, VertexCount * 3);

  CurPt := OriPt;

  //if Assigned(TransformCallback) then
  //  TransformCallback(CurPt);
  CurPt := _TcustomCanvasGPUProtectedAccess(aCanvas).TransformPoint(CurPt);
  //if FAlignToPixels then
  //  AlignToPixel(Result);

  Vertices[0] := CurPt;
  Colors[0] := TalphaColorRec.null;

  for Index := 0 to VertexCount - 1 do
  begin

    if index = VertexCount - 1 then CurPt := OriPt
    else begin

      Angle := (Offset + Index) * 2 * Pi / SubdivCount;

      CurPt.X := Cos(Angle) * Radius.X;
      CurPt.Y := Sin(Angle) * Radius.Y;

      CurPt.Offset(Center);

    end;

    //if Assigned(TransformCallback) then
    //  TransformCallback(CurPt);
    CurPt := _TcustomCanvasGPUProtectedAccess(aCanvas).TransformPoint(CurPt);
    //if FAlignToPixels then
    //  AlignToPixel(Result);

    Vertices[1 + Index] := CurPt;
    Colors[1 + Index] := TalphaColorRec.null;

    Indices[(Index * 3) + 0] := 0;
    Indices[(Index * 3) + 1] := 1 + Index;
    Indices[(Index * 3) + 2] := 1 + ((1 + Index) mod VertexCount);
  end;

  CanvasHelper.FillTriangles(Vertices, Colors, Indices, Length(Vertices), VertexCount);
end;
{$ENDIF}
```